# How to implement "Watch Later" with Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have a photo application where users can add an album to a queue so that he can watch it later.

On each album page they will see "Watch Later" button.

My question is how to design my table for this in Cassandra.

I only need to store album id, album author, album title, display order and date added in the WatchLater table.

**Option 1:**
Copy these values on click and write in the WatchLater table

Pros:
 1) When showing user's watch list, just read from this table

Cons:

1) User may delete the album or change the title anytime. Many users can add a particular album to watch list. During an update of title, I would need to update WatchLater table entries as well.

2) Need another index to find which rows to update

**Option 2:**
Only keep the ids, date added and order in WatchLater table
When showing user's watchList, first get the ids from WatchLater table and then use these ids to pull Album title, author from Albums table

Pros:
No need to worry about update of album Title

Cons:
I need to run 2 queries. So it will be little slower.

Assume that frequency of updating title is not that high.

Which option do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've correctly identified the two options. The real question is balancing the pain of both.

For option 1, do you have a system where you can asynchronously iterate over the various watch lists and update? You may need yet another table that maps album ID to users / watch lists, so you can quickly find the watch lists to update. Does this sound daunting to you? Scheduled/cron tasks may work, but async workers (queue up a list to process, maybe kafka/rabbitmq/spark), for each update, update the albums - not difficult IF you have the framework in place.

For option 2, you just add one extra read. It's probably lower effort to get out the door, and if you're trying to get a product/feature launched, it's quicker and not significant "debt" in terms of "things you'll need to fix later".

Personally, I'd probably tend towards 2, because the extra read can be easily cached for subsequent page loads, and a quick light read probably isn't going to be much pain.